# Write regular expressions for the following languages over the alphabet

Tags: computation-theory

Write regular expressions for the following languages over the alphabet ∑ = {0, 1}:

1. Language of all strings which do not end with 11.
2. Language of all strings which do not contain the substring 01.
   also 
   Draw Finite Automaton for each of the above described languages.

Comment: No. I don't want to. Seriously, though, you're supposed to at least pretend that you've made some effort on your own - show us what you've tried, and explain how it's not working the way you expect it to...

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression for the first one is `e + 0 + 1 + S* (00 + 01 + 10)` where `e` is the empty string, `S` is the alphabet, `*` is the Kleene closure, `+` is union. This works because the language can be divided into strings of length less than two (`e + 0 + 1`) and strings of length at least two which do not end with `11` (this leaves endings `00`, `01`, and `10`).

A regular expression for the second language is `1*0*`. Note that we must put any `1`s on the left of all `0`s to avoid the substring `01`, but we can have as many as either as we like.

A DFA for the first one would look like

```
q    e    q'
q0   0    q0
q0   1    q1
q1   0    q0
q1   1    q2
q2   0    q0
q2   1    q2
```

State q0 is initial, q0 and q1 are accepting. In state q0, you either just started or last saw a zero; your last symbol wasn't 1. In state q1, your last symbol was 1, but your second to last symbol wasn't. In state q2, you have seen two 1s in a row.

A DFA for the second would look like:

```
q    e    q'
q0   0    q1
q0   1    q0
q1   0    q1
q1   1    q2
q2   0    q2
q2   1    q2
```

q0 is the initial state, and q0 and q1 are accepting. q0 reads all the 0s, q1 reads all the 1s, and q2 happens if we see a 0 after we have seen a 1.